# Page getting reloaded on $.post()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

http://twillsonline.in/shirts-2

In this link i have tried to call action using jquery post method. First time of page load when i am trying to select check box i'm getting result but first time check box gets uncheck .. any body can fix this issue.

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")', { parameter:value }, function (data) {
    if (data != null && data.trim() != "") {
        $('#div').html(data);
    }
    else {
        $("#div").html("<h1>No Results Found</h1>");
    }
});
```

here is my code for calling action which returns json result

Comment: Can you be more clear with your question.

Comment: Here my task is sort the page by selected colors so I tried to call the actions based on selected check box using jquery $.post method. I am getting the result but for the first time page gets refreshed partially and selected check box gets uncheck .. I dont know why .. can u please help??
please go through the link once.

Comment: what you have written for it?

Comment: $.post('@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")', { parameter:value }, function (data) {

                if (data != null && data.trim() != "") {
                    $('#div').html(data);
                }
                else {
                    $("#div").html("<h1>No Results Found</h1>");
                }
            });

here is my code for calling action which returns jsonresult

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace few lines in your code and this will work. This is there at the last of the function `sort()`.

```
if (data != null && data.trim() != "") {
    //$('div .page-body').html(data);
    var replaced = data.replace(/\Rs/g, "<del>&#2352;</del> ");
    $('div .page-body').html(replaced);
} else {
    $("div .page-body").html("<h1 style='color:red;' >No Results Found</h1>");
}
```

Good luck!!

Comment: Y m replacing some thing is different its for another requirement. I need to show the result what ever i got from action based on selected colors. I think i m not clear because you did not understand my question.Any how thanks for answering.

Comment: Have you tried it? Try once and see if your problem is solved ir not. Then tell me anything...